# ARM Template Coginitive services

Tags: azure

I need a ARM template for Form Recognizer. It would be helpful if anyone can share a working template for this

ARM template for Form Recognizer

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to create ***form recognizer*** in Azure and test the deployment using below template.

***ARM TEMPLETE:-***

`sample.json`

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"name": {
"type": "string"
},
"location": {
"type": "string"
},
"resourceGroupName": {
"type": "string"
},
"resourceGroupId": {
"type": "string"
},
"sku": {
"type": "string"
},
"tagValues": {
"type": "object"
},
"virtualNetworkType": {
"type": "string"
},
"vnet": {
"type": "object"
},
"ipRules": {
"type": "array"
},
"identity": {
"type": "object"
},
"privateEndpoints": {
"type": "array"
},
"isCommitmentPlanForDisconnectedContainerEnabled": {
"type": "bool"
},
"commitmentPlanForDisconnectedContainer": {
"type": "object"
}
},
"variables": {
"defaultVNetName": "frCSDefaultVNet9901",
"defaultSubnetName": "frCSDefaultSubnet9901",
"defaultAddressPrefix": "13.41.6.0/26"
},
"resources": [
{
"type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
"apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
"name": "deployVnet",
"properties": {
"mode": "Incremental",
"template": {
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
{
"type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
"apiVersion": "2020-04-01",
"name": "[if(equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'External'), parameters('vnet').name, variables('defaultVNetName'))]",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"properties": {
"addressSpace": {
"addressPrefixes": "[if(equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'External'), parameters('vnet').addressPrefixes, json(concat('[{\"', variables('defaultAddressPrefix'),'\"}]')))]"
},
"subnets": [
{
"name": "[if(equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'External'), parameters('vnet').subnets.subnet.name, variables('defaultSubnetName'))]",
"properties": {
"serviceEndpoints": [
{
"service": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices",
"locations": [
"[parameters('location')]"
]
}
],
"addressPrefix": "[if(equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'External'), parameters('vnet').subnets.subnet.addressPrefix, variables('defaultAddressPrefix'))]"
}
}
]
}
}
]
},
"parameters": {}
},
"condition": "[and(and(not(empty(parameters('vnet'))), equals(parameters('vnet').newOrExisting, 'new')), equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'External'))]"
},
{
"apiVersion": "2021-04-30",
"name": "[parameters('name')]",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"type": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts",
"kind": "FormRecognizer",
"tags": "[if(contains(parameters('tagValues'), 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts'), parameters('tagValues')['Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts'], json('{}'))]",
"sku": {
"name": "[parameters('sku')]"
},
"identity": "[parameters('identity')]",
"properties": {
"customSubDomainName": "[toLower(parameters('name'))]",
"publicNetworkAccess": "[if(equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'Internal'), 'Disabled', 'Enabled')]",
"networkAcls": {
"defaultAction": "[if(equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'External'), 'Deny', 'Allow')]",
"virtualNetworkRules": "[if(equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'External'), json(concat('[{\"id\": \"', concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('vnet').resourceGroup, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnet').name, '/subnets/', parameters('vnet').subnets.subnet.name), '\"}]')), json('[]'))]",
"ipRules": "[if(or(empty(parameters('ipRules')), empty(parameters('ipRules')[0].value)), json('[]'), parameters('ipRules'))]"
}
},
"resources": [
{
"type": "commitmentPlans",
"apiVersion": "2021-10-01",
"name": "DisconnectedContainer-FormRecognizer-1",
"properties": "[parameters('commitmentPlanForDisconnectedContainer')]",
"condition": "[parameters('isCommitmentPlanForDisconnectedContainerEnabled')]",
"dependsOn": [
"[parameters('name')]"
]
}
],
"dependsOn": [
"[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', 'deployVnet')]"
]
},
{
"apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
"name": "[concat('deployPrivateEndpoint-', parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].privateEndpoint.name)]",
"type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
"resourceGroup": "[parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].resourceGroup.value.name]",
"subscriptionId": "[parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].subscription.subscriptionId]",
"dependsOn": [
"[parameters('name')]"
],
"condition": "[equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'Internal')]",
"copy": {
"name": "privateendpointscopy",
"count": "[length(parameters('privateEndpoints'))]"
},
"properties": {
"mode": "Incremental",
"template": {
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"resources": [
{
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"name": "[parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].privateEndpoint.name]",
"type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
"apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
"properties": {
"subnet": {
"id": "[parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].privateEndpoint.properties.subnet.id]"
},
"privateLinkServiceConnections": [
{
"name": "[parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].privateEndpoint.name]",
"properties": {
"privateLinkServiceId": "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupId'), '/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/', parameters('name'))]",
"groupIds": "[parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].privateEndpoint.properties.privateLinkServiceConnections[0].properties.groupIds]"
}
}
]
},
"tags": {}
}
]
}
}
},
{
"apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
"name": "[concat('deployDnsZoneGroup-', parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].privateEndpoint.name)]",
"type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
"resourceGroup": "[parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].resourceGroup.value.name]",
"subscriptionId": "[parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].subscription.subscriptionId]",
"dependsOn": [
"[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', concat('deployPrivateEndpoint-', parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].privateEndpoint.name))]"
],
"condition": "[equals(parameters('virtualNetworkType'), 'Internal')]",
"copy": {
"name": "privateendpointdnscopy",
"count": "[length(parameters('privateEndpoints'))]"
},
"properties": {
"mode": "Incremental",
"template": {
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"resources": [
{
"type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups",
"apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
"name": "[concat(parameters('privateEndpoints')[copyIndex()].privateEndpoint.name, '/', 'default')]",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"properties": {
"privateDnsZoneConfigs": [
{
"name": "privatelink-cognitiveservices-azure-com",
"properties": {
"privateDnsZoneId": "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupId'), '/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/privatelink.cognitiveservices.azure.com')]"
}
}
]
}
}
]
}
}
}
]
}
```

We have Saved the parameters in different file and deploy with referencing deployment file as below.

`azuredeploy.parameter.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name":{
            "value": "myrecognizer"
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "westus2"
        },
        "resourceGroupName":{
            "value": "my_resource_group"
        },
        "resourceGroupId": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/subscID/resourceGroups/my_resource_group"
        },
        "sku":{
            "value": "S0"
        },
        "tagValues":{
            "value": {}
        },
        "virtualNetworkType":{
            "value": "None"
        },
        "vnet":{
            "value": {}
        },
        "ipRules":{
            "value": []
        },
        "identity":{
            "value":  {
                "type": "None"
              }
        },
        "privateEndpoints":{
            "value":[]
        },
        "isCommitmentPlanForDisconnectedContainerEnabled":{
            "value": false
        },
        "commitmentPlanForDisconnectedContainer":{
            "value": {
                "current": {},
                "hostingModel": "DisconnectedContainer",
                "planType": "CustomInvoice",
                "autoRenew": true
              }
        }
      
      
       }
    }
```

Deploy using below cmd in terminal :

```
az deployment group create -n TestDeployment -g myresourcegroup --template-file "C:\locationfile\sample.json" --parameters "C:\locationfile\azuredeploy.parameters.json"
```

Below are the ***SCREENSHOT FOR DEPLOYMENT DETAILS:-***

[image]
[image]

---

[image]
[image]